# jQuery: Buttons with a larger picture when user is hovering over it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I'm making a left-horizontal navigation bar in the shape of a bookcase. I making the books laying down horizontally, one on top of each other and each book is a different link.

The buttons have two states, static (just a book) and hovering (a 3d looking book). This gives the effect of the user pulling out the book from the bookcase. Now for the jQuery:

I'm planning to use jQuery to fade the hovering image in on top of the previous image, however I would like to know what would happen if the hovering image is larger by about 10px?

Surely the stack of books would all move down by 10px when one of them has the hovering image faded in?

Help? :)

Comment: http://WhatHaveYouTried.com? And no, not necessarily. Set `position:absolute` to your hover image, it'll be displayed above (in front) of your current page content (provided its z-index is higher).

Comment: question is far too vague as it assumes we know what your css is doing

Answer (score 0):

You could position the larger books with negative margins to overlap the others.
Here's a quick example:

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/5TeHu/

CSS:

```
a{
    display:block;
    width:30px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    margin:10px 1px;
    background:#ddd;   
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}

a:hover{
    width:50px; 
    height:120px;
    margin:0 -9px;
    z-index:2;
}
```

​